# How to decode hexadecimal to text (ASCII)?

Tags: windows-7, windows

How can I decode hexadecimal to text (ASCII)?

Comment: Are you asking about where to find / how to use an ASCII table?  Search for text in a binary file?  More explanation would help.  If it's the former, Google's first hit for ASCII table is: http://www.asciitable.com/ .  If the latter, the answers to this SU question may help: http://superuser.com/questions/124081/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-strings-command .  What do you have and what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) has a free plugin that will do hex-to-ASCII and ASCII-to-hex conversion for you called [NppConverter](http://download.tuxfamily.org/nppplugins/Converter/).

It has been [included in Notepad++ since version v5.9](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-v5.9-is-released.html) (2011-03-31). Thus there is no need to explicitly install it. Its functions are in menu *Plugins* -> *Converter*:

[image: Screenshot of selecting the hex conversion functions in Notepad++]

Answer (score 1):

You may have that backwards. If you're unfamiliar with hex it's best to use an [online tool](http://home2.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/) for this or a [hex editor](http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&complete=0&site=webhp&source=hp&q=hex%20editor&btnG=Search). Otherwise it doesn't take long to get a good understanding of the [principals](http://www.ascii.cl/) involved although I believe these have already been explained here.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [perl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl) or [perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) or [perl](http://win32.perl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Win32_Distributions) installed

```
perl -ne 'print chr hex $1 while /([0-9a-f]{2})/ig
```

e.g

```
perl -ne 'print chr hex $1 while /([0-9a-f]{2})/ig file1 file2 file3 ...
```

or

```
echo 486578 | perl -ne 'print chr hex $1 while /([0-9a-f]{2})/ig
```

(Oops, on Windows use " instead of ' )

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple hex to text chart. It is not complete, for simplicity's sake I am just including characters A-Z

```
hex - character
 41 - A
 42 - B
 43 - C
 44 - D
 45 - E
 46 - F
 47 - G
 48 - H
 49 - I
 4A - J
 4B - K
 4C - L
 4D - M
 4E - N
 4F - O
 50 - P
 51 - Q
 52 - R
 53 - S
 54 - T
 55 - U
 56 - V
 57 - W
 58 - X
 59 - Y
 5A - Z
```

For numbers, take the number's value and add 30 to get the hex code for that number.
Example: 9 + 30 = 39, 0 + 30 = 30, etc.
For lowercase letters, add 20 to the code for the uppercase letter.
Example: A = 41 + 20 = 61 = a

A hex editor, such as Tashcom Software's HexEdit would also help you learn ASCII